# Better solution to display title-Attributes in "disabled" <a>

Tags: html, css

The simplest way to disable `<a>` links is by custom CSS-class "disabled" which sets the pointer-events to none.

How ever title-Attributes where we would like to display the reason why the link is disabled as hover text wont work anymore...
See example below:

```css
a.disabled,
a.disabled:visited {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="link is clickable">active Link with hover text</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="disabled" title="link is disabled because of...">disabled link with hidden hover text</a>
```

I see two possibility which are both not really elegant:

**Wrapping the `<a>` and add title to parent**. But this is an unnecessary wrapping element and may affect styling.

```css
a.disabled,
a.disabled:visited {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="link is clickable">active Link</a>

<br>

<span title="link is disabled because of...">
  <a href="#" class="disabled">disabled link</a>
</span>
```

Since we're using deactivated anchor tags mostly styled as a button, **we could use `<button>` instead**. But unfortunately onclick navigation on buttons can not be opened optionally in a separate windows like `<a>` do (via context menu or click on the middle mouse button). This could be added with additional Javascript but this would be a even worse solution...

```css
a.disabled,
a.disabled:visited {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<button href="#" title="link is clickable" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'">
  active button
</button>

<br>

<button title="link is disabled because of..." onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'" disabled>
  disabled button
</button>
```

I even don't understand why there is no disabled-attribute for `<a>` in the html standard like buttons have...

Any ideas for a really proper solution to disabled anchor tags but still displaying title hover texts? It would be nice to find an CSS only solution or a similar approach.

Comment: What is the end goal here exactly ?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution which does not affect the HTML - a pure CSS solution would be the best in my opinion.

Comment: "I see two possibility which are both not elegant enough for me". Stack Overflow is not a site where we compete for who can produce the most "elegant" answer, and certainly not for just one person. Please [edit] your question to include criteria for what a "proper" solution should entail.

Comment: It sounds like you're using links wrong. Anchors should be used for taking a user from one document to another. If they cannot navigate, there should not be an anchor, or the anchor should not have an `href` attribute.

Comment: Side note `pointer-events: none;` won't prevent key events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the title attribute with disabled links,
you have to modify your code this way:

```
a.disabled {
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: grey;
}
a.disabled:active {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This is an exemple using the attribute `title` and a custom attribute named `data-tooltip` to show the tooltip text:

```css
a.disabled {
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: grey;
}
a.disabled:active {
  pointer-events: none;
}
/* Tooltip **/
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

[data-tooltip]::after {
  pointer-events: auto;
  background: #444;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem -0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);

  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
  max-width: 11rem;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.25rem;

  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: calc(100% + 0.25rem);

  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-10%, 0.25rem);
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  visibility: hidden;

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  z-index: 999;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover::after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0.125rem);
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out, transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<a href="#active" data-tooltip="link is clickable">active Link with hover text</a>
<br>
<a href="#disabled" title="I'm the title attribute" class="disabled" data-tooltip="I'm the data-tooltip attribute">disabled link with hidden hover text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with using a little bit of Javascript, you could simply go like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('a.disabled')) 
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
a.disabled,
a.disabled:visited {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="link is clickable">active Link with hover text</a>
<br>
<a href="https://google.com" class="disabled" title="link is disabled because of...">disabled link with hidden hover text</a>
```